# Dungeon Construction Set

Tags: code-challenge, maze

When I was a kid, I played the Intellivision game [Advanced Dungeons and Dragons: Treasure of Tarmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Dungeons_&_Dragons:_Treasure_of_Tarmin).  The 3-D graphics put you in a first-person-perspective point of view with shocking realism:

[image: Shockingly Realistic 3-D Graphics]

But then I got a C-64.  And I was able to draw on the 40x25 character grid by cursoring around the screen, setting the color with the Ctrl key and a digit, and putting symbols anywhere I wanted *(why doesn't `bash` let me do that?)*.  The character set had triangular components and solid block components.  So I was able to reason through how one might generate a rendering of one's perspective in a grid through that medium.

I found the nearly-three-decades-old spec, in spiral-bound notebook paper, about "Dungeon Construction Set" this week:

[image]

*(**UPDATE**: Careful readers will notice that this doesn't quite hold together on the slanted parts.  Corrected numbers are provided below.)*

Though Treasure of Tarmin was played on a grid, the walls existed only on the *edges* of grid squares.  Having learned what bytes were, I realized that if I made the map out of bytes...then each square on the map could have four possible states for each of its edges:

1. Unobstructed
2. Wall
3. Door
4. Something Else?

I never did get around to writing it (until last night).  I thought it might be fun for others to try.

So your task is to implement a character-mode-based maze renderer that implements my *(corrected!!)* spec...but using the technologies of 2013.

### Input

Because the spec doesn't define rendering for doors, we'll just assume the only options are wall-and-not-wall.  For simplicity, your input is a map composed of lines of strings that look like this:

```
WN.. .N.. .N.. .N.. .N.E
W... .... .... ..S. ...E
W... .N.E W... .N.. ...E
W... .... .... .... ...E
W.S. ..S. ..S. ..S. ..SE
```

That would be a 5x5 map.  The upper left corner (1,1) has its `W`est and `N`orth wall set.  The lower right corner (5,5) has its `S`outh and `E`ast wall set.

This is considerably less fun with no map navigation.  So at minimum, put your player at (1,1) facing north and offer them:

```
[F]orward, [B]ackward, turn [L]eft, turn [R]ight or [Q]uit?
```

At each step, output a 16x15 display of the first-person perspective, as defined by the notebook paper spec.  To keep you from having to count, the size of flat walls at the three distances are:

```
14x13  (directly in front of you; e.g. wall is in same cell)
8x7    (one step away)
6x5    (two steps away)
```

The bounding sizes of the slanted walls are:

```
1x15   (your direct left or right; e.g. wall is in same cell)
3x13   (one step away)
1x7    (two steps away)
```

### Clarifications

- Adjacent cells may disagree about shared walls.  So the south edge on a square might be a wall, while the north edge on the square to the south of it would be unobstructed.  In the original design I considered this a feature: it permits interesting ideas like one-way doors...or invisible walls that only appear after you passed through them.  For this simplification, follow the same rule: for navigation and rendering, pay attention only to the edge status on the cell *closest to you in the direction you are facing*.
- The view is a lot better with "shading".  So for your full blocks, alternate either Unicode 2593 ▓ and 2591 ░, or use `X` and `+` if your implementation is ASCII.
- Unicode triangle characters (25E2 ◢, 25E3 ◣, 25E4 ◤, 25E5 ◥) are a bit lame for drawing this.  Besides not having any shaded variants, they often stretch only the width of the character and not the full height...even in fixed width fonts.  You can draw full blocks or slash characters or something of your choosing in the places I wanted diagonals.  Interesting creative solutions that incorporate color and use these characters instead of shading appreciated.
- You may assume the outermost walls are set to bound the playing area, so you don't have to worry about rendering anything outside of the maze.  Any walls farther away from you than the spec are ignored and just leave empty space.
- The shading of the wall you see directly in front of you if facing North at (1,1) should be DARK.  Alternate shading on adjacent walls in the map, such that if all walls were present then a light wall would never abut a dark wall.
- A C-64 implementation that actually does what I originally intended...with the diagonal characters and all...will trump any other entry criterion.  :-)

### Examples

For the sample map given above...

At (1,3) facing south:

```
               /
              /+
             /X+
            /XX+
           /XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
           \XXX+
            \XX+
             \X+
              \+
               \
```

At (3,2) facing south:

```
                      /* blank line */        
X             /
X            /+
X           /++
X           +++
X           +++
X           +++
X           +++
X           +++
X           +++
X           +++
X           \++
X            \+
X             \
                      /* blank line */
```

At (3,2) facing east:

```
                      /* blank line */        
              / 
             /X 
            /XX 
            XXX 
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
            XXX 
            \XX 
             \X 
              \ 
                      /* blank line */
```

At (2,3) facing north:

```
               /
 ++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
X++++++++++++++X
X++++++++++++++X
X++++++++++++++X
X++++++++++++++X
X++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
 ++++++++++++++X
               \
```

Comment: I suggest making this a [tag:code-challenge] - a golf would be way too unreadable and hard :P

Comment: @Doorknob Don't let it fool you...it's actually not all that hard.  There's a pretty good hint with the lists of 3 bounding sizes.  And what is a golf but a challenge that is solved and then pared down?  :-)  But I'll let people pick how they want to solve it... NP

Comment: Could you please explain the two columns of `X`s in your view of `3, 2` facing south?

Comment: Especially the one on the right hand side. I see why the left one is there. But the right one seems to violate Clarification #1.

Comment: @jazzpi Oops, you're right, the map I put up does need to obey clarification 1!  Well done.  Fixed.  *(I'd put the missing south wall in on my own version at some point apparently...but good to have a test case in the sample...so let's leave the south wall out!)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Commodore 64 Basic

Man, that was fun. And hard. C64 Basic is almost undebuggable, you can't even use `print` debugging because the screen is already taken for rendering the dungeon. You know you're having fun when you're writing code like `55250 goto 55110`. Dijkstra will kill me.

The program uses two colors, and diagonal characters.

Needless to say I didn't golf it. It says *code challenge* now, after all. It's **7183** bytes if you're interested.

It's slow - at default speed it takes several seconds for it to render the scene. The maximum map size is 10 by 10 but it can be changed by editing line 120.

I have developed and tested this using the **VICE** emulator. The code below is displayed in ASCII, so that means *shifted* PETSCII. *However, when inputting the map, you should use **unshifted** PETSCII*.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
10 rem c64 dungeon construction set.
20 rem enter using lowercase mode
99 rem DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
100 rem initialisation
110 poke 53272,21
115 poke 53280,0
120 dim m%(10,10)
121 dim di$(3),wa$(1),ma%(2,2)
122 di$(0)="north"
123 di$(1)="east "
124 di$(2)="south"
125 di$(3)="west "
126 wa$(1)="-wall"
127 wa$(0)="     "

130 x=0:y=0:di=0:xs=0:ys=0:wa=0
134 rem read map
135 print "input map"
140 l$="":input l$
150 if len(l$)=0 goto 250
160 cz=0
170 for i=1 to len(l$)
180   c$=mid$(l$,i,1)
190   if c$="n" then cz=cz or 8
200   if c$="e" then cz=cz or 4
205   if c$="s" then cz=cz or 2
210   if c$="w" then cz=cz or 1
215   if c$=" " then m%(x,y)=cz:cz=0:x=x+1
220   if x>=xs then xs=x
225 next
230 m%(x,y)=cz:x=0:y=y+1
240 goto 140
250 rem come from 150
260 print chr$(147)
265 ys=y:xs=xs+1
270 x=0:y=0

500 rem loop
510 gosub 1000: rem status
515 gosub 2000: rem render
520 gosub 55000: rem input
530 goto 500

1000 rem display current (x,y) value
1010 sx=5
1020 sy=17
1030 sl$="    "
1035 sw=14
1040 gosub 63900
1050 cz=m%(x,y)
1060 sx=5:sl$=".":if cz and 8 then sl$="n"
1065 gosub 63900
1070 sx=6:sl$=".":if cz and 4 then sl$="e"
1075 gosub 63900
1080 sx=7:sl$=".":if cz and 2 then sl$="s"
1085 gosub 63900
1090 sx=8:sl$=".":if cz and 1 then sl$="w"
1095 gosub 63900
1100 return

2000 rem render dungeon
2010 rem DDDDDDDDDDDDDD
2020 rem clear area
2030 sw=14:sz=32
2040 for sy=0 to 15
2050   for sx=0 to 16
2060      gosub 63950
2070   next
2080 next
2090 rem find cells / reorient sw
2100 rem store in ma% - we're at (0,1)
2110 sx=x:sy=y
2113 co=di+x+y and 1
2115 for ty=0 to 2
2120    gosub 59800:rem left/right sx/sy
2125    ma%(1,ty)=0
2126    if sx>=0 and sy>=0 and sx<xs and sy<ys then ma%(1,ty)=m%(sx,sy)
2130    ma%(0,ty)=rl
2140    ma%(2,ty)=rr
2150    gosub 59900:rem advance
2160 next
2170 rem draw back walls
2180 sa=ma%(1,2):gosub 59700
2190 if rf=0 goto 2245
2195 sw=14-11*co:sz=160
2200 for sy=5 to 9
2210    for sx=5 to 10
2220       gosub 63950
2230    next
2240 next
2245 sw=3:if co=1 then sw=14
2250 for de=0 to 2 step 2 
2260    sa=ma%(de,2):gosub 59700
2270    if rf=0 goto 2350
2280    for sx=de*5.5 to 4+de*5.5
2290       for sy=5 to 9
2300          gosub 63950
2310       next
2340    next 
2350 next
2360 rem 1,2 left wall
2370 sa=ma%(1,2):gosub 59700
2380 if rl=0 goto 2430
2390 sx=4:sz=160
2400 for sy=5 to 9:gosub 63950:next
2410 sy=4:sz=223:gosub 63950
2420 sy=10:sz=105:gosub 63950
2430 rem 1,2 right wall
2440 if rr=0 goto 2490
2450 sx=11:sz=160
2460 for sy=5 to 9:gosub 63950:next
2470 sy=4:sz=233:gosub 63950
2480 sy=10:sz=95:gosub 63950
2490 rem 1,1 back wall
2500 sa=ma%(1,1):gosub 59700
2510 sz=160
2520 sw=14:if co=1 then sw=3
2520 if rf=0 goto 2580
2530 for sy=4 to 10
2540    for sx=4 to 11
2550       gosub 63950
2560    next
2570 next
2580 rem (0-2),1 back walls
2590 sw=14:if co=1 then sw=3
2600 for de=0 to 2 step 2
2610    sa=ma%(de,1):gosub 59700
2620    if rf=0 goto 2680
2630    for sx=de*6 to 3+de*6
2640       for sy=4 to 10
2650          gosub 63950
2660       next
2670    next
2680 next 
2690 rem 1,1 left side wall
2700 sw=14:if co=1 then sw=3
2710 sa=ma%(1,1):gosub 59700
2720 if rl=0 goto 2760
2730 for sx=1 to 3
2735   sy=sx:sz=223:gosub 63950
2736   sy=14-sx:sz=105:gosub 63950
2737   sz=160
2740   for sy=1+sx to 13-sx:gosub 63950:next
2750 next
2760 rem 1,1 right side wall
2770 if rr=0 goto 2850
2780 for qx=1 to 3
2790   sx=15-qx
2800   sy=qx:sz=233:gosub 63950
2810   sy=14-qx:sz=95:gosub 63950
2820   sz=160
2830   for sy=1+qx to 13-qx:gosub 63950:next
2840 next
2850 rem 0,1 back wall
2860 sa=ma%(1,0):gosub 59700
2870 if rf=0 goto 2930
2880 for sy=1 to 13
2890   for sx=1 to 14
2900     gosub 63950
2910   next
2920 next
2930 rem (0,2)-0 back walls
2940 sw=3:if co=1 then sw=14
2950 for de=0 to 2 step 2
2960   sa=ma%(de,0):gosub 59700
2970   if rf=0 goto 3000
2980   sx=de*7.5
2990   for sy=1 to 13:gosub 63950:next
3000 next
3010 rem (1,0) left side wall
3020 sa=ma%(1,0):gosub 59700
3030 if rl=0 goto 3080
3040 sx=0:sy=0:sz=223:gosub 63950
3050 sy=14:sz=105:gosub 63950
3060 sz=160
3070 for sy=1 to 13:gosub 63950:next
3080 rem (1,0) right side wall
3085 if rr=0 goto 3130
3090 sx=15:sy=0:sz=233:gosub 63950
3100 sy=14:sz=95:gosub 63950
3110 sz=160
3120 for sy=1 to 13:gosub 63950:next
3130 rem done
3140 return

55000 rem ask for prompt & handle input
55010 sx=0:sy=20:gosub 63850
55013 print "at";x+1;y+1;"going ";di$(di);" size";xs;ys;wa$(wa)
55020 print "{f}rwd {b}kwd {l}eft {r}ight {q}uit"
55030 input c$
55040 if c$="q" goto 63999
55050 if c$="f" then dm=1:goto 55100
55060 if c$="b" then dm=-1:goto 55100
55070 if c$="l" then di=(di-1)and 3
55080 if c$="r" then di=(di+1)and 3
55090 return
55100 goto 55200:rem check walls
55110 if di=0 then y=y-dm
55120 if di=1 then x=x+dm
55130 if di=2 then y=y+dm
55140 if di=3 then x=x-dm
55145 wa=0
55146 if y>=ys then y=0
55147 if y<0   then y=ys-1
55148 if x>=xs then x=0
55149 if x<0   then x=xs-1
55150 return
55200 rem check walls
55205 cz=m%(x,y)
55207 if dm=-1 goto 55280
55210 if (di=0) and (cz and 8) goto 55260
55220 if (di=1) and (cz and 4) goto 55260
55230 if (di=2) and (cz and 2) goto 55260
55240 if (di=3) and (cz and 1) goto 55260
55250 goto 55110
55260 wa=1
55270 return : rem wall in the way
55280 rem backward
55290 if (di=2) and (cz and 8) goto 55260
55300 if (di=3) and (cz and 4) goto 55260
55310 if (di=0) and (cz and 2) goto 55260
55320 if (di=1) and (cz and 1) goto 55260
55330 goto 55110

59700 rem return front/back/left/right
59710 rem given sa and d
59720 sn=0:if sa and 8 then sn=1
59725 se=0:if sa and 4 then se=1
59730 ss=0:if sa and 2 then ss=1
59735 zw=0:if sa and 1 then zw=1
59740 if di=0 then rf=sn:rr=se:rb=ss:rl=zw
59745 if di=1 then rf=se:rr=ss:rb=zw:rl=sn
59750 if di=2 then rf=ss:rr=zw:rb=sn:rl=se
59755 if di=3 then rf=zw:rr=sn:rb=se:rl=ss
59760 return

59800 rem return left/right from sx/sy/d
59810 if di=0 then ly=sy:ry=sy:lx=sx-1:rx=sx+1
59820 if di=1 then lx=sx:rx=sx:ly=sy-1:ry=sy+1
59830 if di=2 then ly=sy:ry=sy:lx=sx+1:rx=sx-1
59840 if di=3 then lx=sx:rx=sx:ly=sy+1:ry=sy-1
59850 rl=0:rr=0
59860 if lx<0 or lx>=xs or ly<0 or ly>=ys goto 59880
59870 rl=m%(lx,ly)
59880 if rx<0 or rx>=xs or ry<0 or ry>=ys goto 59895
59890 rr=m%(rx,ry)
59895 return

59900 rem step forward
59910 if di=0 then sy=sy-1:rem N
59920 if di=1 then sx=sx+1:rem E
59930 if di=2 then sy=sy+1:rem S
59940 if di=3 then sx=sx-1:rem W
59950 return

63850 rem set cursor position
63851 rem sx=x sy=y
63860 poke 781,sy
63870 poke 782,sx
63880 poke 783,0
63890 sys 65520
63895 return

63900 rem write str to screen
63901 rem sl$ = string
63910 gosub 63850
63920 print sl$;
63930 return

63950 rem write chr to screen
63951 rem sx = x coordinate
63952 rem sy = y coordinate
63953 rem sz = character code
63954 rem sw = color
63950 sv=sx+sy*40
63960 poke 1024+sv,sz
63970 poke 55296+sv,sw
63980 return

63998 rem quit program
63999 print chr$(147):end
```

Tape image: [download here](http://frankenstein.d-n-s.org.uk/~marinus/dungeon.tap).

The examples:

[image: examples]

Comment: OMG.  If others want to solve this for the heck of it, great... but you have won the bounty by definition of the trump card in the challenge.  I was tempted to pull out an emulator and do it for nostalgia reasons, but thought it was more productive to write it in [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/p/about.html) to see how well the compiler cross-compiler could hold-up.  [source for that](https://github.com/hostilefork/teenage-coding/blob/master/DUNGEON/dungeon.red).  I'll [Rebmu-ify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDKaz1iB9wQ) it and post it at some point...but the bounty is yours!  Big applause.

Comment: Also, RE: Dijkstra, he has a [funny quote on immortality](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra): *"I mean, if 10 years from now, when you are doing something quick and dirty, you suddenly visualize that I am looking over your shoulders and say to yourself 'Dijkstra would not have liked this', well, that would be enough immortality for me."*  So I guess he got his wish!  :-)

Comment: @Dr.Rebmu: thanks for the bounty! This took me literally all day to write :)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

> *(why doesn't `bash` let me do that?)*

I just had to now.

### Bash, 12743 chars

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IFS=
declare -a term
typeset -i term[0] term[1]
IFS=' ' read -a term <<< `stty size`
front[0]='\e[2;2H██████████████
\e[3;2H██████████████
\e[4;2H██████████████
\e[5;2H██████████████
\e[6;2H██████████████
\e[7;2H██████████████
\e[8;2H██████████████
\e[9;2H██████████████
\e[10;2H██████████████
\e[11;2H██████████████
\e[12;2H██████████████
\e[13;2H██████████████
\e[14;2H██████████████'
front[1]='\e[5;5H████████
\e[6;5H████████
\e[7;5H████████
\e[8;5H████████
\e[9;5H████████
\e[10;5H████████
\e[11;5H████████'
front[2]='\e[6;6H██████
\e[7;6H██████
\e[8;6H██████
\e[9;6H██████
\e[10;6H██████'
lfront[0]='\e[2;1H█
\e[3;1H█
\e[4;1H█
\e[5;1H█
\e[6;1H█
\e[7;1H█
\e[8;1H█
\e[9;1H█
\e[10;1H█
\e[11;1H█
\e[12;1H█
\e[13;1H█
\e[14;1H█'
lfront[1]='\e[5;1H████
\e[6;1H████
\e[7;1H████
\e[8;1H████
\e[9;1H████
\e[10;1H████
\e[11;1H████'
lfront[2]='\e[6;1H█████
\e[7;1H█████
\e[8;1H█████
\e[9;1H█████
\e[10;1H█████'
rfront[0]='\e[2;16H█
\e[3;16H█
\e[4;16H█
\e[5;16H█
\e[6;16H█
\e[7;16H█
\e[8;16H█
\e[9;16H█
\e[10;16H█
\e[11;16H█
\e[12;16H█
\e[13;16H█
\e[14;16H█'
rfront[1]='\e[5;13H████
\e[6;13H████
\e[7;13H████
\e[8;13H████
\e[9;13H████
\e[10;13H████
\e[11;13H████'
rfront[2]='\e[6;12H█████
\e[7;12H█████
\e[8;12H█████
\e[9;12H█████
\e[10;12H█████'
left[0]='\e[1;1H▙
\e[2;1H█
\e[3;1H█
\e[4;1H█
\e[5;1H█
\e[6;1H█
\e[7;1H█
\e[8;1H█
\e[9;1H█
\e[10;1H█
\e[11;1H█
\e[12;1H█
\e[13;1H█
\e[14;1H█
\e[15;1H▛'
left[1]='\e[2;2H▙
\e[3;2H█▙
\e[4;2H██▙
\e[5;2H███
\e[6;2H███
\e[7;2H███
\e[8;2H███
\e[9;2H███
\e[10;2H███
\e[11;2H███
\e[12;2H██▛
\e[13;2H█▛
\e[14;2H▛'
left[2]='\e[5;5H▙
\e[6;5H█
\e[7;5H█
\e[8;5H█
\e[9;5H█
\e[10;5H█
\e[11;5H▛'
right[0]='\e[1;16H▟
\e[2;16H█
\e[3;16H█
\e[4;16H█
\e[5;16H█
\e[6;16H█
\e[7;16H█
\e[8;16H█
\e[9;16H█
\e[10;16H█
\e[11;16H█
\e[12;16H█
\e[13;16H█
\e[14;16H█
\e[15;16H▜'
right[1]='\e[2;13H  ▟
\e[3;13H ▟█
\e[4;13H▟██
\e[5;13H███
\e[6;13H███
\e[7;13H███
\e[8;13H███
\e[9;13H███
\e[10;13H███
\e[11;13H███
\e[12;13H▜██
\e[13;13H ▜█
\e[14;13H  ▜'
right[2]='\e[5;12H▟
\e[6;12H█
\e[7;12H█
\e[8;12H█
\e[9;12H█
\e[10;12H█
\e[11;12H▜'

echo -e "\e[2J"

# Read map
typeset -i cout
cout=0
echo "Please input your map!"
echo "Please input the next row (or leave it blank if you're finished!)"
read input

declare -A map

typeset -i xlen ylen
ylen=0

until [ -z $input ]
do
    IFS=' ' read -a inputmap <<< "$input"
    xlen=${#inputmap[*]}
    let ylen++
    for index in "${!inputmap[@]}"
    do
        typeset -i map[$index,$cout]
        map[$index,$cout]=0
        el=${inputmap[index]}
        if [[ $el == W??? ]]
        then
            let "map[$index,$cout]|=1"
        fi
        if [[ $el == ?N?? ]]
        then
            let "map[$index,$cout]|=2"
        fi
        if [[ $el == ??S? ]]
        then
            let "map[$index,$cout]|=4"
        fi
        if [[ $el == ???E ]]
        then
            let "map[$index,$cout]|=8"
        fi
    done
    echo "Please input the next row (or leave it blank if you're finished!)"
    read input
    cout+=1
done

echo -ne "\e[2J"

typeset -i dir x y
dir=0
x=0
y=0

move() {
    if ((dir == 0)) && ( ((${map[$x,$y]} & 2)) || ((y == 0)) )
    then
        return 1
    elif ((dir == 1)) && ( ((${map[$x,$y]} & 8)) || (($x == $xlen)) )
    then
        return 1
    elif ((dir == 2)) && ( ((${map[$x,$y]} & 4)) || ((y == $ylen)) )
    then
        return 1
    elif ((dir == 3)) && ( ((${map[$x,$y]} & 1)) || ((x == 0)) )
    then
        return 1
    fi
    x=$1
    y=$2
}

input=

until [[ $input == [qQ] ]]
do
    if [[ $input == [DlL] ]]
    then
        let dir-=1
        if (( dir == -1 ))
        then
            dir=3
        fi
    elif [[ $input == [CrR] ]]
    then
        let dir+=1
        if (( dir == 4 ))
        then
            dir=0
        fi
    elif [[ $input == [AfF] ]]
    then
        if (( dir == 0 ))
        then
            move $x $(( y-1 ))
        elif (( dir == 1 ))
        then
            move $(( x+1 )) $y
        elif (( dir == 2 ))
        then
            move $x $(( y+1 ))
        elif (( dir == 3 ))
        then
            move $(( x-1 )) $y
        fi
    elif [[ $input == [bB] ]]
    then
        if (( dir == 0 ))
        then
            dir=2
            move $x $(( y+1 ))
            dir=0
        elif (( dir == 1 ))
        then
            dir=3
            move $(( x-1 )) $y
            dir=1
        elif (( dir == 2 ))
        then
            dir=0
            move $x $(( y-1 ))
            dir=2
        elif (( dir == 3 ))
        then
            dir=1
            move $(( x+1 )) $y
            dir=3
        fi
    fi
    echo -ne "\e[2J"
    echo -ne "\e[16;1Hd=$dir; x=$x; y=$y\e[48;5;29m"
    for (( y2=1; y2 <= 15; y2++ ))
    do
        echo -ne "\e[$y2;16H\e[1K"
    done
    if (( dir == 0 ))
    then
        for (( y2=(y-2); y2 <= y; y2++ ))
        do
            if (( y2 < 0 )); then continue; fi
            let i=y-y2
            if (( x > 0 )) && (( ${map[$((x-1)),$y2]} & 2 ))
            then
                if (( ((x-1) + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${lfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( (x+1) < xlen )) && (( ${map[$((x+1)),$y2]} & 2 ))
            then
                if (( ((x-1) + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${rfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x,$y2]} & 1 ))
            then
                if (( (x + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${left[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x,$y2]} & 8 ))
            then
                if (( (x + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${right[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x,$y2]} & 2 ))
            then
                if (( (x + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${front[$i]}
            fi
        done
    elif (( dir == 1 ))
    then
        for (( x2=x+2; x2 >= x; x2-- ))
        do
            if (( x2 > 16 )) || (( x2 >= xlen )); then continue; fi
            let i=x2-x
            if (( y > 0 )) && (( ${map[$x2,$((y-1))]} & 8 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + (y-1)) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${lfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( (y+1) < ylen )) && (( ${map[$x2,$((y+1))]} & 8 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + (y-1)) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${rfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x2,$y]} & 2 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + y) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${left[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x2,$y]} & 4 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + y) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${right[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x2,$y]} & 8 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + y) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${front[$i]}
            fi
        done
    elif (( dir == 2 ))
    then
        for (( y2=(y+2); y2 >= y; y2-- ))
        do
            if (( y2 > 15 )) || (( y2 >= ylen )); then continue; fi
            let i=y2-y
            if (( x > 0 )) && (( ${map[$((x-1)),$y2]} & 4 ))
            then
                if (( ((x-1) + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${rfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( (x+1) < xlen )) && (( ${map[$((x+1)),$y2]} & 4 ))
            then
                if (( ((x+1) + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${lfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x,$y2]} & 8 ))
            then
                if (( (x + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${left[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x,$y2]} & 1 ))
            then
                if (( (x + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${right[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x,$y2]} & 4 ))
            then
                if (( (x + y2) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${front[$i]}
            fi
        done
    elif (( dir == 3 ))
    then
        for (( x2=(x-2); x2 <= x; x2++ ))
        do
            if (( x2 < 0 )); then continue; fi
            let i=x-x2
            if (( y > 0 )) && (( ${map[$x2,$((y-1))]} & 1 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + (y-1)) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${rfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( (y+1) < ylen )) && (( ${map[$x2,$((y+1))]} & 1 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + (y+1)) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${lfront[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x2,$y]} & 4 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + y) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${left[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x2,$y]} & 2 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + y) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${right[$i]}
            fi
            if (( ${map[$x2,$y]} & 1 ))
            then
                if (( (x2 + y) & 1 ))
                then
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;28m"
                else
                    echo -ne "\e[38;5;40m"
                fi
                echo -ne ${front[$i]}
            fi
        done
    fi
    echo -ne "\e[0m"
    echo -ne "\e[${term[0]};0H[F]orward, [B]ackward, turn [L]eft, turn [R]ight or [Q]uit?"
    read -n 1 input
done

echo
```

Please keep in mind that this is pretty much the first thing I did with `bash` that was more than just piping a few commands together. It would probably be reducable by quite a lot if I didn't hardcode all the walls, but it seemed easier. It's got no consistency whatsoever. The byte format for each square is picked in a horrible way. But it works.

I even added support for movement through the arrow keys :)

These are some screenshots for the sample input ( Note that my map starts at (0|0) ):

[image: 0|0, facing north]
[image: 0|2, facing south]
[image: 2|1, facing east]
[image: 2|1, facing south]
[image: 1|2, facing north]

<strike>Apart from the fourth one they all look like the sample ones as well (see my comment on the OP).</strike>

These screenshots were taken on urxvt v9.15 with 256 color support, it probably would look quite crap on a 88 color terminal, and terminals without unicode support don't work at all. The font I used was [Source Code Pro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecodepro.adobe/) by Adobe.

Comment: Haha, in bash, and in color too!  Nice.  You were totally right about that wall, apparently I had at some point "fixed it" in my program.  [So I un-fixed it.](https://github.com/hostilefork/teenage-coding/commit/eddf6742c07f544383a8754fe79ae41899d7ec13) :-)  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my version, in Python 3. It's something like 3k characters and could get a bit smaller with a little effort (there's lots of white space that could be removed, to start with).

It currently uses `+X/\` as its drawing characters, but it is set up to draw with Unicode characters if you have a fixed width font that will render them properly. It supports using separate tiles for the angled parts of the differently collored walls, though I'm not using that feature. It also lets you provide ceiling, floor and "distant" tiles, and you can use different ones for when the player is facing east or west vs north or south. Alas this never looked very good, so probably all of these should be blank (or something solid, like `█`).

Alas, on my Windows 7 system I had a horrible time trying to find a monospaced font with the full set of block characters (e.g. `▜` and `▟`). Most of the ones I found could not be made available in the `cmd` console for some reason (perhaps because they're not perfectly monospaced?). If you think your console is more functional, try using the alternate character set that I've commented out near the top of the file, which doesn't look too bad even with just two colors. It has filled in ceilings and floors and mostly transparent walls.

The code:

```
from itertools import product as p
r=range
cs=r"+X//\\//\\      " #" ░▛▛▜▜▟▟▙▙██████"
shapes=[(1,[(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(5),r(5,10))]),
        (0,[(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(5,11),r(5,10))]),
        (1,[(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(11,16),r(5,10))]),
        (1,[(4,4,4),(4,10,6)]+[(4,y,0)for y in r(5,10)]),
        (1,[(11,4,2),(11,10,8)]+[(11,y,0)for y in r(5,10)]),
        (0,[(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(4),r(4,11))]),
        (1,[(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(4,12),r(4,11))]),
        (0,[(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(12,16),r(4,11))]),
        (0,[(1,1,4),(2,2,4),(3,3,4),(1,13,6),(2,12,6),(3,11,6)]+
           [(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(1,4),r(2,14)) if x<y<14-x]),
        (0,[(14,1,2),(13,2,2),(12,3,2),(14,13,8),(13,12,8),(12,11,8)]+
           [(x,y,0)for x,y in p(r(12,15),r(2,14)) if 15-x<y<x-1]),
        (1,[(0,y,0) for y in r(1,14)]),
        (0,[(x,y,0) for x,y in p(r(1,15),r(1,14))]),
        (1,[(15,y,0) for y in r(1,14)]),
        (1,[(0,0,4),(0,14,6)]+[(0,y,0)for y in r(1,14)]),
        (1,[(15,0,2),(15,14,8)]+[(15,y,0) for y in r(1,14)])]
def rr(s):
    for r in s:print("".join(r))
def dw(s,a,p,d):
    for i,r in enumerate(s):r[:]=cs[10+i//5*2+d%2]*16
    for w,(pl,sh) in zip(a,shapes):
        if w:
            for x,y,c in sh:
                s[y][x]=cs[c+(p+d+pl)%2]
dx=[1,0,-1,0]
def ga(x,y,d,m):
    fx=dx[d];fy=lx=dx[d-1];ly=dx[d-2]
    return [m[y+2*fy+ly][x+2*fx+lx][d],m[y+2*fy][x+2*fx][d],
            m[y+2*fy-ly][x+2*fx-lx][d],m[y+2*fy][x+2*fx][d-1],
            m[y+2*fy][x+2*fx][d-3],m[y+fy+ly][x+fx+lx][d],
            m[y+fy][x+fx][d],m[y+fy-ly][x+fx-lx][d],
            m[y+fy][x+fx][d-1],m[y+fy][x+fx][d-3],
            m[y+ly][x+lx][d],m[y][x][d],
            m[y-ly][x-lx][d],m[y][x][d-1],m[y][x][d-3]]
def rd():
    l=input();
    while l!="":
        if "\n" in l:yield from l.split("\n")
        else:yield l
        l=input()
def rm():
    m=[[[d in s for d in"ESWN"]for s in r.strip().split()]+[[1]*4]*2
       for r in rd()]
    return m+[[[1]*4 for _ in m[0]]]*2
def cl():print("\n"*30)
def gl():
    print("Enter map, followed by a blank line.")
    x=y=0;d=3;m=rm();mv="";s=[[""]*16 for _ in r(15)]
    while True:
        cl();dw(s,ga(x,y,d,m),x+y,d);rr(s)
        print("X:",x+1,"Y:",y+1,"Facing:","ESWN"[d])
        if mv:print("Last move:",mv)
        mv=input("[FBLRQ]? ").upper()
        if mv=="F":
            if not m[y][x][d]:x+=dx[d];y+=dx[d-1]
            else:mv+=" (Blocked)"
        elif mv=="B":
            if not m[y][x][d-2]:x+=dx[d-2];y+=dx[d-3]
            else:mv+=" (Blocked)"
        elif mv=="L":d=(d-1)%4
        elif mv=="R":d=(d+1)%4
        elif mv=="Q":break
        else:mv="I didn't understand %r."%mv
gl()
```

The character set is specified near the top of the file. The order of the characters are:

1. even parity wall
2. odd parity wall
3. even parity top right wall angle (e.g. `/` with a wall below it)
4. odd parity top right wall angle
5. even parity top left wall angle
6. odd parity top left wall angle
7. even parity bottom right wall angle
8. odd parity bottom right wall angle
9. even parity bottom left wall angle
10. odd parity bottom left wall angle
11. ceiling facing E/W
12. ceiling facing N/S
13. horizon facing E/W (the middle of the screen if there are no walls)
14. horizon facing N/S
15. floor facing E/W
16. floor facing N/S

There are 15 walls that might need to be rendered by the game, in a pattern like this (with `V` indicating the player's position and arc of view):

```
_ _ _
_|_|_ 
_|_|_
 |V|
```

The tiles used by the 15 walls are defined in the `shapes` list. It's a list of 2-tuples. The first value of the tuple indicates the "parity" of the wall, with `0` indicating that it should be drawn with the same characters as a wall directly in front of the character and a `1` indicating that it should be the alternate pattern (e.g. `+` vs `X`). The second value is a list of `x,y,t` tuples indicating the screen coordinates and tile index of one pixel (walls being rendered with odd parity will have `1` added to each of these indexes). The shapes are ordered by distance, so the first three represent the perpendicular walls two tiles ahead of the character, followed by the two parallel walls two tiles ahead, and so on.

The functions are:

- `rr`: "render" the screen (by printing the tiles in the screen buffer).
- `dw`: "draw walls" to a provided screen buffer. This uses the painters algorithm, so the most distant walls are drawn first and may get covered up by closer ones.
- `ga`: "get area" returns a list of boolean values indicating which walls are opaque for a given map position and facing.
- `rd`: "read", a generator that reads the map, yielding the lines. This is only needed because IDLE's console does weird stuff when you paste multi-line inputs rather than entering one line at a time.
- `rm`: "read map", parses the map into a nested list of booleans, indexed by `m[y][x][d]` (with `d=0` being East and `d=1` being South). It also adds two rows and two columns of padding squares, to avoid index errors in the other code.
- `cl`: "clear" the output (by writing enough newlines to scroll the old view off the top of the most consoles).
- `gl`: "game loop", where the input is gathered and the above stuff gets called.

A few "screenshots":

The starting position:

```
\               
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX+
/               
X: 1 Y: 1 Facing: N
[FBLRQ]?
```

Looking along the north wall:

```
\               
X\              
X+\             
X++\            
X+++\           
X+++X           
X+++X           
X+++X           
X+++X           
X+++X           
X+++/           
X++/            
X+/             
X/              
/               
X: 1 Y: 1 Facing: E
Last move: R
[FBLRQ]?
```

A couple of shots matching your examples (note, the blank first lines are being chopped off by Stack Overflow, they're in the program output):

```
X             / 
X            /+ 
X           /++ 
X           +++ 
X           +++ 
X           +++ 
X           +++ 
X           +++ 
X           +++ 
X           +++ 
X           \++ 
X            \+ 
X             \ 

X: 3 Y: 2 Facing: S
Last move: F
[FBLRQ]?
```

And:

```
              / 
             /X 
            /XX 
            XXX 
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
+++++XXXXXX+XXX+
            XXX 
            \XX 
             \X 
              \ 

X: 3 Y: 2 Facing: E
Last move: L
[FBLRQ]?
```

Here's one of the stranger views in the supplied map, as the wall parallel to our view is the same color as the perpendicular wall sticking out behind it:

```
 \              
 +\             
 ++\            
++++        ++++
++++        ++++
++++        ++++
++++        ++++
++++        ++++
++++        ++++
++++        ++++
 ++/            
 +/             
 /              

X: 3 Y: 4 Facing: N
Last move: R
[FBLRQ]?
```

Here's what the area of last shot would look like from above:

```
_   _
 |
  V
```

Comment: Nice added analysis and diagrams!  Hm, those walls wind up being the same color on that last one in my implementation too.  Good point about the edge case.  I didn't think that would happen, but it sort of has to.  Guess it's like map coloring, and two colors isn't actually enough... :-/